# Error while trying to link GitHub and DockerHub with Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, github, dockerhub

I have an error related to my Dockerfile.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL maintainer="******@gmail.com"
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Doing the build using this Dockerfile locally works.

my `.jar` is generated inside `build / libs / *. jar`

so I upload my project to git and try to build through DockerHub and get it.

```
Step 6/7: ADD $ {JAR_FILE} spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder278372549/build/libs/spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

because these folders are not in the project in git

I'm trying to learn more about Docker, can anyone help me better design this Dockerfile to solve this problem?

i am using:

Spring boot 2.1.5.RELEASE

Gradle

Trying link GitHub <-> DockerHub

Comment: try  `ADD build/libs/$ {JAR_FILE} spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar`

Comment: `Step 6/7 : ADD build/libs/$ {JAR_FILE} spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder044093754/build/libs/$: no such file or directory` - does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL maintainer="******@gmail.com"
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java",-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar ]
ADD build/libs/spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar`

Comment: `Step 5/6 : ENTRYPOINT ["java",-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar ]
---> Running in d749cf1a5971
Removing intermediate container d749cf1a5971
---> 88c8c5d6ca66
Step 6/6 : ADD build/libs/spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder203642380/build/libs/spring-swagger-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory`  --does not work `from github -> docker hub` and locally it builds, but when i do `docker ps` it does not work, it does not have port, even me doing `docker run -d -p 12345: 8080 * .jar`